# java project base directory is not expected value

Tags: java

I have a dynamic web project, if I want to reference file paths in this project, the base location of the file is under

```
C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse
```

However under another console project, the base directory path is:

```
C:\Users\myName\workspace_test\THE_CONSOLE_PROJECT
```

This is what I expect. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something like Unix style eg.

```
File f = new File("./test.txt");
```

> `./` should be actual location (usually "src" of project, if you run .jar from cmd it should be location where jar file is, something like that :)

or simply this should also work

```
File f = new File("test.txt");
```

Edit- 2nd command under win works like actual location:

```
File f = new File("./test.txt");
File f2 = new File("test.txt");

System.out.println("f absolute path: " + f.getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("f2 absolute path: " + f2.getAbsolutePath());
```

> f absolute path: C:\Users\user\workspaceTEST\clearTest.\test.txt
>
> f2 absolute path: C:\Users\user\workspaceTEST\clearTest\test.txt

And also for path separator is better to use `File.separator` , than hard `"\" or "/"`